# How to deploy my application on multiple target

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX installer and I would like to deploy my application on 10 computers. They are connected to a network. Actually, I run my installer on each computer.

I'm wondering if I can install my application on all computers with only one execution of my installer.

Is that possible with WiX? Or should I try to send the installer to each computer to run thereafter? I searched on Google and StackOverflow but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Please take more care with your spelling and your grammar. I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a server in your network?

You could deploy group policies which run the installer from an network-directory.

See:  http://www.itninja.com/blog/view/the-guide-to-deploying-software-using-group-policy

Comment: No, I don't have a server in my network. I will check group policy